# QWebEngine JS function execute external doesn't start C++ function if it contains null

Tags: javascript, c++, qt

For example. JS function is

```
executeExternal('download',45145,null,true).then(function(result{console.log(result)})
```

It doesn't start C++ function

```
bool download(QString ID1,QString ID2,bool bVal) {
    return true;
}
```

But

```
executeExternal('download',45145,7645,true).then(function(result{console.log(result)})
```

does start C++ functions. What should I do? In QWebKit it looked like this

```
window.external.download(45145,null,true)
```

And it was working

Comment: It doesn't make sense to cast null to a QString. What does that even mean? (For that matter, casting an integer to a QString doesn't make much sense either, but I guess it works because of Javascript's wacky type system.)

Comment: Thanks. Looks like you're right. Since JS code was also rewritten, so maybe this was the problem